# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response

Tags: android, exception, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I want to make a search to a row in the database. I put this query in my code

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query_names = ParseQuery.getQuery("PhoneBook");
            query_names.include("Numbers");
            query_names.whereStartsWith("Name", searchString.toLowerCase());
            query_names.setLimit( 20);
            query_names.findInBackground();
```

I got this exception

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response

Comment: what is `AsyncrechercheTask`? and where is used this response?

Comment: AsyncrechercheTask dont have any role

Comment: I'm getting the same error from a different input as well, starting last night. I've narrowed it down to where you log in/initialize parse/put in the keys and found out it wasn't going through at that point. Try clearing your app data. If anyone is getting the same error for similar things please let me know!

Comment: Please let me know if you find any solution

Comment: Am sorry i dont found any solution yet

Answer (score 1):

This exception is from the parse version
in my buid.gradle i have used a compile like this:

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

the best way is to put like this

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
```

and it will work correctly

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have forgotten the trailing slash like I did. It causes this error.

```
.server("http://localhost:1337/parse/") // The trailing slash is important.
```